# Error: basic_istream<char> to non-scalar type cxx11::string while using getline

Tags: c++, c++11

I just started a c++ class at my school and I am starting to learn the language. For one school problem I am trying to skip lines in a text file using getline.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
int np;
ifstream fin("gift1.txt.c_str()");
string s;
fin >> np;
string people[np];

for(int counter = 0; counter == 1 + np; ++counter)
{
    string z = getline(fin, s)
    cout << z << endl;
}
}
```

Every time I try to compile that I get the error

> gift1.cpp:22:21: error: conversion from 'std::basic_istream' to non-scalar type 'std::__cxx11::string {aka std::__cxx11::basic_string}' requested

Is there any simple solution to this?

Comment: getline doesn't return a string http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline, try removing `string z =` to begin with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have so many problems in this code - so instead of giving you a comment - I added comments to your code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int np;
    ifstream fin("gift1.txt.c_str()");
    string s; // declare this inside the loop
    fin >> np;
    string people[np]; // This is a Variable Length array. It is not supported by C++
                       // use std::vector instead

    for(int counter = 0; counter == 1 + np; ++counter) 
    // End condition is never true, so you never enter the loop. 
    // It should be counter < np
    {
        string z = getline(fin, s) // Missing ; and getline return iostream 
                                   // see next line for proper syntax

        //if(getline(fin, s))
                cout << z << endl; // Result will be in the s var. 
                                   // Discard the z var completely
    }
}
```